# YARP Redirects Instead Of Forwarding With Status Code 308

Tags: kubernetes, redirect, forward, ms-yarp, http-status-code-308

I have a strange problem with my YARP project as ApiGateWay, it redirects API URLs With a status code 308 and I don't know the main reason why. I have two environments, one for development and one for production. In the Production Environment, it forwards requests correctly, but in the Development Environment it redirects requests.
In both of them I have a such a setting :

```
"myproject": {
        "ClusterId": "myproject",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "/prj/{**remainder}"
        },
        "Transforms": [
          {
            "PathPattern": "/{**remainder}"
          }
        ]
      }
```

my development environment runs in kubernetes, does it related ?